# Main menu display description as span tag

Tags: theming, navigation

I modifed my main menu using the following code, but I need the `<span class="description">` elements only for the first level menu items, not for the sub-menu items.

How can I achieve this?

```php
function neofelis_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';
  $element['#localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  
  if ($element['#original_link']['menu_name'] == "main-menu" && isset($element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'])) {
    $element['#title'] .= '<span class="description">' . $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'] . '</span>';
  }
  
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your friend is: `$element['#original_link']['depth'];`

You would adjust your conditional to be something like:

```
 // Not sure if top level depth is 0 or 1 for this so experiment with that a bit.
 if ($element['#original_link']['menu_name'] == "main-menu" && 
     isset($element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title']) &&
     $element['#original_link']['depth'] == 0
 ){
    $element['#title'] .= '<span class="description">' . $element['#localized_options']['attributes']['title'] . '</span>';
 }
```

Check out [this comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/19004#comment-19004) from the drupal documentation.